# Using IF statement formula in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a hard time figuring out the error in my code. I need to use IF statement formula in VBA excel. However, I am getting an error "Application-defined or object-defined error" in the below code:

```
.Range("G2:G" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX('VLookupTable'!$D$2:$D$184,MATCH(F9,'VLookupTable'!$C$2:$C$184,0))),"",INDEX('VLookupTable'!$D$2:$D$184,MATCH(F9,'VLookupTable'!$C$2:$C$184,0)))"
```

If I removed the IF statement, it is working. It returns true or false, but I need to check the condition if the value is N/A, it should return the value instead of TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: You have to escape quotes when you whant to pass them inside a string. Replace `...)),"",IN...` by `...)),"""",IN...`

Comment: Your `VLOOKUP` functions don't need to be wrapped in apostrophes: `'` and you also appear to be mixing up your parameter order, as you're specifying the range to search before the item to find. Also, what Vincent said.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The VLookup in my code is actually a name of the table. I changed it to something else to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Clearly I've not had enough coffee yet. Makes more sense now! But Vincent's comment should sort you out.